# Different treatment periods and times in difference-in-differences

Tags: regression, difference-in-difference

I am conducting a study on hiring foreign CEOs over domestic US CEOs and the effect their culture has on innovation in the period 2000-2014. Within this period I obviously have different comparison periods (e.g. 2002-2009, 2003-2008).

How do I get that into one difference-in-differences regression? I am also adding firm controls, do I need to use those for e.g. 2002 and 2009 only and add these in my regression?

Comment: So the outcome is number of innovations at a given firm and the treatment is hiring a non-US CEO which happens at different points in time? Also what kind of controls do you have?